# What is canonical cover, closure and extraneous attribute?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, functional-dependencies, canonical-form

I'm studying database concepts and there are 3 concepts that I don't understand: canonical cover, extraneous attribute and closure. I read the definition about canonical cover but I don't get the picture of how it relates to 3NF and BCNF. The definition of canonical cover appears to be that there are no extraneous attributes and extraneous attributes are attributes that don't change the closure of the set of functional dependencies and closure is the set of all functional dependencies implied by F, a set of functional dependencies.

But all this is a little fuzzy and I'd like to know both an intuitive definition and how to calculate

- Canonical cover
- Closure
- Extraneous attribute

Functional dependency I believe I understand--it's like what would have been the PK in a table if we had those attributes in a table.

There is a rather extensive answer at [database refinement - minimal cover of F (extraneous attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008354/database-refinement-minimal-cover-of-f-extraneous-attributes) but I found it difficult to read all the set definitions and algebra and I'd rather have definitions in plain English.

For example, having the schema U={A,B,C,D,E,F,G} and the functional dependencies

```
AB → C
B → E
CF → D
C → A
B → F
CE → F
CD → B
B → C
```

Are the closures A+,B+,C+,D+,E+,F+ calculated this way?

```
A+ = A
B+ = BCDEF
C+ = A
D+ = D
E+ = E
F+ = F
```

If I'm not mistaken then BCDEFG is a superkey (”the whole key”) in 1NF/2NF but is it minimal (3NF)?

What else should be done to normalize this example to 1NF, 2NF and 3NF with the help of closures and canonical covers? Is canonical cover the same as minimal cover?

Comment: The reason you don't understand is that paraphrases of what "it's like" are not adequate, one must find, memorize & use precise definitions. They are inescapable. (And once doing that "algebra" is more manageable than "plain English".) PS This is just asking for us to rewrite a textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You made some mistakes:

For the closures:

- `B+` should be `ABCDEF` rather than `BCDEF` because of the FD `C → A`
- `C+` should be `AC` (the closure of an attribute always contains itself)
- `G+` is `G`, see reason of the second bullet

To calculate the canonical cover, follow this algorithm. You need to look at your list of functional dependencies:

1. Left reduction: try to remove all attributes of the left side of the arrow that are not necessary to create the same closure.
   To make the first example, `AB → C`, you can calculate `AB`s closure, which would be `ABCDEF`. You then try to remove `A`, ending up with `B → C`. Now you calculate the closure of `B` only, which is still `ABCDEF` -> you can remove A.
   At the end of this step, your FD should look like `{B → C, B → E, C F → D, C → A, B → F, C E → F, C D → B, B → C, G → G}`.
2. Now you make the same thing for the right hand side. Note that you can remove *all* attributes here if you want, ending up with the empty set. As an example, look at `B → F`: the closure of `B` is `ABCDEF`. If you remove the `F` from the functional dependency, ending up with `B → ∅`, you still got the same closure for `B` as before. Repeat that for the other FDs.
   You should end up with `{B →∅, B → E, C F → D, C → A, B →∅, C E → F, C D → B, B → C, G →∅}`.
3. Remove all FDs of the form `X → ∅`. You end up with `{B → E, C F → D, C → A, C E → F, C D → B, B → C}`.
4. Combine all FDs that have the same left-side of the arrow, which leads to a canonical cover of `{B → C E, C F → D, C → A, C E → F, C D → B}` .

For the superkeys: see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5736174/1641070)

Comment: I didn't got the second point in canonical forms :( why did you dropped B → F to be B → ∅ an  G → ∅ as well

Comment: Alright, I'll give you an example of the right reduction. If you try to reduce the FD `B → F`, you can see that there exist the FD `B → E`, `B → C` and `C E → F`. Because the latter three imply `B → C E F`, one says that `F` is extraneous in `B → F`.
As for `G → G`, an attribute always implies itself (`G+` is `G`), so you can remove the right side.

Answer (score 1):

> Are the closures A+,B+,C+,D+,E+,F+ calculated this way?

What happened to "G"? Its absence here is significant. Do you know why?

> If I'm not mistaken then BCDEFG is a super key (”the whole key”) in
>   1NF/2NF but is it minimal (3NF)?

*Superkey* (one word, no spaces) doesn't mean *the whole key*; it just means *a key*. The set of all attributes is a trivial superkey, so {ABCDEFG} is a trivial superkey.

Since B->C and C->A (a transitive dependency), you can reduce the trivial superkey to {BCDEFG}.  Several more reductions are possible, so {BCDEFG} isn't a minimal superkey. {BCDEFG} is a *reducible* superkey.

*One* of the minimal superkeys is {BG}. (I could say, "{BG} is an irreducible superkey.") There are other minimal superkeys.

> What else should be done to normalize this example to 1NF, 2NF and 3NF
>   with the help of closures and canonical cover?

Just in case you have a common misunderstanding of this, it's not generally possible to normalize to 2NF *and no higher*, or to normalize to 3NF *and no higher*. Eliminating partial-key dependencies ("normalizing to 2NF") can leave all your relations in 5NF.

The next step is to determine all the candidate keys (all the irreducible superkeys).

Answer (score 1):

Derived from the Algorithm given in Database System Concepts by Korth:

> Are the closures A+,B+,C+,D+,E+,F+ calculated this way?

Steps to calculate the closures of A,B,C,D,E and F under F, for example for B:

1. result = {B}
2. repeat

   3. for each functional dependency(e.g `B -> E`) in `F` do

      4. begin
      5. if `B` is subset of result
      6. then `result(i.e B) = result(i.e B) U {E}`
      7. end

8. until (result stops changing)

So the closures are:
A+ = A
B+ = ABCDEF
C+ = AC
D+ = D
E+ = E
F+ = F

An attribute **A** is extraneous in a dependency  alpha(AB) -> beta(C) if:

1. **A** belongs to beta(which is not in the current case) then create new FD
   `F' = (F-{alpha -> beta}) U {alpha -> (beta - alpha)}`
   and check if `alpha+ under F'(**not F**) includes A`, then `A` is extraneous in `beta`.
2. **A** belongs to alpha(which is correct), then create a new `gamma{B} = alpha({AB}) - {A}` and check if `gamma+(i.e B+)` under `**F** i.e ABCDEF` includes all attributes in `beta({C})` and which is true. So **A** is extraneous in `AB->C`.

Similarly checking if `C` is extraneous in `AB->C`:

1. `F' : AB -> NULL; B →E; CF →D; C →A; B →F; CE →F; CD →B; B →C`
2. Compute `AB+` under `F'` i.e `ABCDEF` which includes `C` . So `C` is extraneous in `AB-> C`.

Algorithm to compute the canonical cover of F:

1. `F' = F`
2. If there is any FD like `A->B and A->C` then replace by `A->BC`(by union rule). Here the F' becomes:
   `AB -> C; B-> CEF; C -> A; CD-> B; CE-> F; CF-> D`
3. Find the extraneous(left/right) in F' i.e `A is extraneous in AB->C` so remove `A from AB->C` , so that it becomes `B->C` and update `F'`.
4. Now check if F' is changed. If changed go to step 2 and repeat until find the F' no longer changes.

Second iteration:

`F' : B -> C; B-> CEF; C -> A; CD-> B; CE-> F; CF-> D`
`F' : B-> CEF; C -> A; CD-> B; CE-> F; CF-> D`
Now check `C in B-> CEF`, which is not extraneous
Check E , which is also not extraneous.
check F ,which is extraneous.
So new `F' :  B-> CE; C -> A; CD-> B; CE-> F; CF-> D`

Third iteration:

`F' :  B-> CE; C -> A; CD-> B; CE-> F; CF-> D`

After this there no further extraneous attribute are found.

So the canonical cover of F is:
`B-> CE`
`C -> A`
`CD-> B`
`CE-> F`
`CF-> D`

Answer (score 0):

yes Canonical cover is same as minimal cover.
and all the closures are correct

to make the example in 3NF..

1. just find the canonical cover
2. make relations of each individual fds. ie.. if Fc={AB->C,C->D} then make R1(ABC) & R2(CD).
3. Now check if candidate key is contained in any one relation. if yes then its in 3NF
   and if no then add one more relation that contains only that candidate key.
   and its done..!!

Comment: Not all the closures are correct as pointed out by Lukas above.