# Finding functional dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

I have gotten the following task in an assignment:

> In the following tasks assume the relation R(A, B, C, D, E) with the
>   following functional dependencies:
>
> AB → C, BC → D, CD → A, E → D
>
> Solve the following tasks: List all keys of R and explain why
>   there can be no other.

How do I find the keys in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Keys from Functional Dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735592/determine-keys-from-functional-dependencies)

Comment: I have seen that, but I didn't get it.

Comment: Try to leave a comment on the other question. Also clarify what exactly was unclear in the answer over there.

Comment: You could also look at this question: [How to find a candidate key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465696/how-to-find-a-candidate-key).